# How to change the font color of a DT table based on another matrix in R

Tags: r, datatable

I have two matrices: the first has the data that I want to show and the other has the values that are going to be used to select the color of the font. The thing is that I don't know how to change the color based on the second matrix with the `DT` package in R, i have done it with respect to columns in the main matrix but can't figure out how to do it with respect to another matrix.

This is what i have:

```
data = matrix(rnorm(100),10,10)
colnames(data) = as.character(seq(as.Date(Sys.Date()),as.Date(Sys.Date()+10), length.out = 10))
data_2 = matrix(runif(100),10,10)
colnames(data_2) = as.character(1:10)
data_final = cbind(data,data_2)

datatable(data_final,
          options = list(paging = FALSE, dom = 'tip',columnDefs = list(list(visible=F,
          targets =  c(10:20)))))%>%
  formatPercentage(colnames(data_final),2)
```

I think it shoud be something like this:

```
  formatStyle(1:4, valueColumns=5:8,
              color = JS("value < 0 ? 'red' : value > 0 ? 'green' : 'blue'"))
```

where 1:4 are the columns I want to change the color, 5:8 are the values to compare, but in the `color = JS` it should be change in some way that it compares the colum 1 with the column 5, and so on to decided the color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use `styleInterval` like this:

```
formatStyle(columns = 1:10, valueColumns = 11:20, color = styleInterval(c(-1e-10, 1e-10), c('red', 'blue', 'green')))
```

Here we use two breaks at `-1e-10` and `+1e-10`. Everything in between, so basically the zeros, will be blue.

Comment: doesn't work for me because each value in the second matrix is the one that i have to use to compare. The interval would be the same to all the elements in the matrix `data` and as I say each element has a value to comparer in the `data_2`

Comment: So you basically have no columns `5:8` in `data_final`? Tell me what should change in the image I added.

Comment: @ Martin Schmelzer Yes I have, `data_final` is a matrix with 20 columns, the first ten are going to be display and the other 10 are going to be use, or I want to use them, as the value it has to compare to change the color of the first 10. So each element of the first 10 columns should be compare to its corresponding element in the last 10

Comment: So `nrow` is the same for both matrices. Why does the combination of `cbind` btoh matrices and hiding the second matrix' columns not work?

Comment: Yeah it is the same for both matrix and the `cbind` works for me. Why hide the second? Because I don't want to show that data I just want to use it to change the colors which I haven't been able to do

Comment: Yes that I do understand. What i do not understand is why setting `columns = 1:10` and `valueColumns = 11:20` does not work?

Comment: Because then I know how to change the color if the `value` in the `valueColumns` is less, greeter or equal to a number that's going to be the same for all like 0, but that's not what I need

Comment: I am sorry, I dont get it. If I cbind `data_1` and `data_2` (each having 10 columns), then hide columns `11:20` and format the values in column 1 according to the values in column 11, the values of column 2 according to the values in column 12, and so on. Then this is what you want according to what you wrote in your question. If not, please try to be a little more precise.

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I want

Comment: Because your code change the red the negative, to green the positive and to blue the 0 but in my real data all the values in columns 11:20 are positive, but thinking I know how to make your example to work

Comment: That was because of your example: I selected columns 5:8 as valueColumns. When I use 11:20 it works and all are green.....?!?

Comment: Ok i think my example was miss leading. The condition should be column1>column11 then green or column1<column11 then red. Your code doesn't do that. But if  i modified my second matrix I can make it work